# how to solve the warning in proc read function?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, proc, procfs

[about /proc read and write functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101026/about-proc-read-and-write-functions?rq=1)

I used the code from the above link and I am getting the same warning as shown in that link. I am just using  a read function to read from the kernel to the user space. I look at the solution given by the other person and it was not clear and all the reference provided by the user is not working. So someone please tell me how to solve the warning  ??

after giving the make command in the console. it will throw an warning as : warning initialization from incompatible pointer type and later if I give insmod then it wont work. could someone guide me in this ??

Comment: The answer to the duplicate question is that the types of the arguments to the supplied read/write functions do not match those declared in the definition of the respective function-pointer types.  Simply make them agree or force by casting to shut the compiler up (I really would not recommend the latter course however).

Comment: @Clifford: could you please specify the changes in that program ??

Comment: You should ask that perhaps in a comment to the answer given if it is not clear rather than raising a duplicate question just to get an answer *you* understand. It is quite simple your definitions of `read_proc` and `write_proc` do not have the same signature (parameter and return types) as the members you are assigning them to.  I cannot suggest a fix, and a fix was not suggested because it is not possible to determine what was intended in the original code.

Comment: I am new user here. So i am not able to comment there.

Comment: There is an example [here](http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x569.html) that may help.  Your proc_read/proc_write functions should have the same parameter and return types as the device_read/device_write functions used in this example.

Comment: Your question was closed because you were essentially asking "can you give another answer to the question asked here?".  You would do better to ask a question about your specific problem and your specific code.  Since that code was already known to be broken, what possessed you to use it!?